# How to include subscript in axis labels of a scatter3D plot in R

Tags: r, expression, axis-labels, scatter3d, plot3d

I want to make a scatter 3D Plot with `PC_1` and `PC_3` (subscripts) as labels of the x- and z-axis. I would usually do it with `expression(PC[1])` but it doesn't work. I just can't find a way to solve the problem.

```
library(plot3D)

par(mar = c(4, 0, 3.2, 2))
scatter3D(pc$PC1, pc$PC2, pc$PC3, phi = phi, theta = 180,
      colvar = as.integer(sz$t)/60, clab = c("Zeit in", "Minuten"),
      col = ramp.col(c("deepskyblue", "blue", "darkorchid", "violetred", "red")),
      bty = "b2", type = "b", ticktype = "detailed",
      pch = 20, lwd = 2, cex.lab = 1.4, cex.axis = 1.4, cex = 1,
      colkey = FALSE, main = "",
      xlab = expression(PC[1]), ylab = "", zlab = expression(PC[3]),
      xlim = c(min(pc), max(pc)), ylim = c(min(pc), max(pc)), zlim = c(min(pc), max(pc))
)
```

It just shows `PC[1]` and `PC[3]` as axis labels. `PC["1"]` and `"PC"["1"]` or any other combination also don't work.

Comment: That doesn't work. See a solution [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-include-superscripts-and-subscripts-on-axis-from-hist3d-plots-plot3d-package/17064/2), with `text3d`. Good luck!

Comment: That doesn't work for me as I can't place a text outside of the plots "box".